# Potential overload while using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management

I am trying to use multi-threading  to call a method over million times. So i am using `ExecutorService` and passing the `newFixedThreadPool` with a dynamic value of:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
```

This is initiating thousands of threads, will this lead to heavy load on the processor? Or will it be ok to go with it?

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
ArrayList<Future<Boolean>> arrList = new ArrayList<Future<Boolean>>();
    for (final Vlaue val : List) {

        arrList.add(service.submit(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {

                Object obj = client.findObj(
                        val.getItem1(),val.getItem2());
                return obj.isValid();
            }
        }));

    }
    service.shutdown();
    for (Future future : arrList) {
        // at time future returns null here, not sure why?
        assertTrue("Invalid object" future.get());            
    }
```

Comment: _This is initiating thousands of threads_ What? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` threads.

No matter how many tasks you submit to it they will just be queued up and processed by those threads when they become available.

So in other words what you are doing is fine although your use of `Future`'s seems a little strange. There is most likely a more efficient way to do that but what you are doing will work.

Comment: I made the appropriate change, wanted to use future to print invalid objects for me. How every it returns few nulls at times